# CubeJS - Use Subqueries in queryRewrite

Tags: javascript, cube, cube.js

I have an application in CubeJS which will receive a JWT with a user_id claim.

The table that contains this also has a list of ids from another table.

The idea is to use a subquery so the user can only access data containing a member of this list of IDs.

Something like

```
SELECT posts FROM posts 
where posts.user_id IN 
(
   SELECT allowed_ids AS ids FROM users 
   WHERE user_id = '9bef1222-f1ee-4879-a60e-16e94e88df28'
)
```

But the issue is that I have access only to the query object from cubeJS, and I'm not sure how can I add a subquery to it.

This is an example of the code filtering only by the user_id:

```
cube.js


module.exports = {
  queryRewrite: (query, { securityContext }) => {

    query.filters.push({
      member: "users.id",
      operator: "equals",
      values: [securityContext.user_id],
    });


    return query;
  },
};
```